# Weird SQL query behavior

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using a select query to parse address, for some reason both like and charindex don't work.
The data rows are like below:

```
Address
204‐101 xx CREEK DR
168‐906 xx RD
168‐906 xx RD
```

I tried query like

```
select top 10 ascii(substring(address,4,1)),
ascii('-'),
charindex(substring(address,4,1) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,address),
charindex('-',address collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS),
addr1=case when charindex('‐',address)>0 then substring(address,charindex('‐',address)+1,200) else address end
```

The result is like below

```
45  45  4   0   204‐101 xx CREEK DR
45  45  4   0   168‐906 xx RD
45  45  4   0   168‐906 xx RD
```

So the dash in the address has ascii code 45. But for some reason, charindex with dash returns 0, while charindex with the substring to get the dash in the address works.

I suspect it is the collation, but I did convert the addresses into my server's collation already.

Any idea? thanks！

Answer (score 1):

They are different characters. The one in the data is [`NCHAR(8208)`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2010) and the one in the string literal is [`NCHAR(45)`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002D) - you should use the [`UNICODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/unicode-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to see this not [`ASCII`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EyWbNFkJ))

Calling `ASCII` will implicitly convert the string to `varchar` and characters can be silently changed to close equivalents.